# Creating duplicate posts from my WordPress blog over to Posterous

Tags: rss, wordpress, blog, posterous

How do I set up my WordPress blog to also post those entries at Posterous?

I have the RSS feed from the WordPress site and would like to have it replicate over to the Posterous one without having to manually copy and paste the entries over.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 4):

There is a plug-in that will cross post your WordPress blog to Posterous - it is called [Posterize](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posterize/)